# C - How can I copy one string into an element of character arrays?

Tags: c

I'm trying to parse a file and have an array of character pointers whose length is the number of lines in the file. I want to copy each line into an element of this array, but keep getting a segmentation fault. I don't see what I'm doing wrong, so if anybody could help it would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

```
char * unsplitLines[numLines];
char line[20];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < lines; i++)
{
    fgets(line, 20, fp);
    //printf("%s\n", line);
    unsplitLines[i] = line;
}
```

The gets function works fine, but the assignment after it causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: What is the value of `numLines`? What is the value of `i`? What's the point in setting every entry in `unsplitLines` to point to the same place?

Comment: Assuming you fix the definition of `unsplitLines` (or it is already OK), you still have to allocate the memory that each `unsplitLines[i]` points at.  Otherwise, all the entries point at the same (rather small) array and you only see the last line entered after the loop.  Consider the merits (or otherwise) of the POSIX function [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` do not allocate buffer for you, so all the elements in `unsplitLines` store same pointer `line` and its content is the end line of file.

try `asprintf`

```
char * unsplitLines[numLines];
char line[20];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < lines; i++)
{
    fgets(line, 20, fp);
    asprintf(unsplitLines[i], "%s", line);
}
```

Comment: Be careful recommending non-standard functions (e.g. `asprintf - These functions are GNU extensions, not in C or POSIX.`) Recommending `strdup` or `strlen`, `malloc` and `strcpy`, would be standard ways.