# C - How to store tokens returned by strtok() into an array of char pointers?

Tags: c, string, parsing

I have a char pointer to a string taken in from a text file that I would like to split up line by line and store into an array. My code is here:

```
char * token;
char * unsplitLines[lines];
const char * s = "\n";

int i = 0;
while((token = strtok(rawFile, s)) != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", token);
    char * temp = malloc(20);
    strcpy(temp, token);
    unsplitLines[i] = temp;
    free(temp);
    rawFile = NULL;
    i++;
}
```

where `unsplitLines` represents each line in the text file, and `rawFile` is the entire text file that I'm trying to split up. Each line is at most 15 characters, so I allocated 20 bytes just to be safe. I can get the tokens correctly, but the trouble arises when trying to save it in `unsplitLines[i]`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't use `free(temp)` there if you want to access the strings later.  Also, I'm suffering from deja vu.  There was a similar question (same basic scenario, but without the memory allocation) asked last night.  It seems to have been deleted now.  Was that you too?

Comment: Re: deja vu.  The similar question (same basic scenario, but without the memory allocation) was [How can I copy one string into an element of character arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248643/c-how-can-i-copy-one-string-into-an-element-of-character-arrays)

Comment: Yes, that was me. I'm really struggling with this concept and nothing being suggested seems to be working for me. Maybe another problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Please note that 
"unsplitLines[i] = temp" does not copy a line

Comment: There could be other problems — this is why we ask for an MCVE ([MCVE]) — actual code we can compile and run.  We have to take it on good faith that `lines` is initialized appropriately in your code, but I could easily imagin scenarios where you've not initialized it properly (they keep cropping up in questions on SO).  We can't diagnose the problems in the code we can't see.  Providing us with an MCVE is good experience — you get to make a copy of your program and eliminate all but the elements that contribute to your problem.

Comment: @teroi: true (`unsplitLines[i] = temp;` does not copy the line), _but_ the preceding `strcpy(temp, token)` does copy the token into the allocated storage and that pointer is assigned to `unsplitLines[i]` OK.  There isn't proper attention to sizes and overflows — instead of `malloc(20)` it should be `malloc(strlen(token) + 1)` which works correctly regardless of the size of the token.  The allocation should be checked, too; if the return value is a NULL pointer, there are problems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, I know. :-) I accidentally pressed add comment before finished. The point was that I was under impression that the original poster somehow is distracted to think so. Point was that unplitLines is just an array char pointers. They are not "Lines" as one might think by just viewing the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm goes along those lines. Important to note, `strtok` first parameter must be null after the first call. However, `split` methods are inefficient, and `strtok` should be the preferred way in C. It's a bit hard to use when you're used to `java`'s or `C#`'s split methods, but it has its perks.

```
char *str = "/some/path/i/want/to/split";
char *dup = strdup(str);

int i = 0;
char *split[32];
char *tok = strtok(dup, "/");

while (tok != NULL)
{
    split[i++] = tok;
    tok = strtok(NULL, "/");
}

// handle split before freeing dup

free(dup);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't store pointer to temporary storage.

```
char * temp = malloc(20); // this is temporary
.
.
free(temp); // after this any pointer to temp buffer is invalid
```

Solution: do not use strcpy(). Instead, operate directly on the rawFile and store pointers to that into unsplitLines.

```
char * token;
char * unsplitLines[lines];
const char * s = "\n";

int i = 0;
char* pointerForStrtok = rawFile;
while((token = strtok(pointerForStrtok, s)) != NULL)
{
    pointerForStrtok = NULL;
    printf("%s\n", token);
    unsplitLines[i] = token;
    i++;
}
```